# Update `offsetWidth` value on browser resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, window-resize, matchmedia

I have a horizontal scrolling div with several child items. Depending on the width, child items can get cropped. So you might get 4 and a 1/2 visible items. So I've used Javascript to force a width to evenly distribute the child items.

I've used Javascript to detect the width of `.palette` and divide that by the number of items I want to show (minus margins) and applied that to each `.swatch`. Not sure if there's a better/simpler way?

If this is the solution, I need a bit of help making this more responsible so it updates on resize of window.

1. I'd like the `offsetWidth` to update on resize so the widths update.
2. Is it possible to use `matchMedia` to use a different value above certain 'breakpoints'? This is partially working!

```js
let palette = document.querySelector('.palette');
let paletteWidth = palette.offsetWidth;
let swatch = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch')

swatch.forEach((item) => {
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 700px)").matches) {
    item.style.width = (paletteWidth - 40) / 5 + "px";
    } else {
    item.style.width = (paletteWidth - 30) / 4 + "px";
    }
});

const handleResize = () => {
    let paletteWidth = palette.offsetWidth;
};

window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
```

```css
.p-card {
  background: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.palette {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.palette__inner {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
}

.palette__inner::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.palette__group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.palette__title {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: sticky;
  align-self: flex-start;
  left: 0;
}

.palette__swatches {
  display: flex;
}

.swatch {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-card">

  <div class="palette">
    <div class="palette__inner">
    
       <div class="palette__group">
        <h4 class="palette__title">Classic</h4>
        <div class="palette__swatches">
          <div class="swatch" style="background: red;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: red;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: red;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: red;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: red;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: red;"></div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      
      <div class="palette__group">
        <h4 class="palette__title">Matte</h4>
        <div class="palette__swatches">
          <div class="swatch" style="background: blue;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: blue;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: blue;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: blue;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: blue;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: blue;"></div>
        </div>     
      </div>
      
      <div class="palette__group">
        <h4 class="palette__title">Glimmer</h4>
        <div class="palette__swatches">
          <div class="swatch" style="background: green;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: green;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: green;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: green;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: green;"></div>
          <div class="swatch" style="background: green;"></div>
        </div>  
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that in your `resize` callback function, you're just updating the width of the parent element (`.palette`) but not the width of the children elements (`.swatch`).

### New JS code to adopt:

```js
let palette = document.querySelector('.palette');
let swatchs = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch')

function setSwatchWidth(n = 5) {
  let paletteWidth = palette.offsetWidth;
  swatchs.forEach((swatch) => {
    swatch.style.width = (
      paletteWidth - (n-1) * 10
    ) / n + "px";
  });
}
onload = () => setSwatchWidth();
onresize = () => setSwatchWidth();
```

**Bonus:** I made the function more generic so that you can choose how many children you want in the sliding window.

Comment: That's ace! Thanks a lot, I'm a total novice so just getting the basic JS working was a challenge for me. I got this far but you's is much better/dynamic: https://jsfiddle.net/2jdyoq6L/ ...out of interest on that if I refresh loads the width is wrong and sometimes stars at the end/middle of the carousel. But I think that might just be an issue with running it in JSFiddle?

Comment: And with 'n' your counting the children minus '1'. Multiplying that by 10. Then dividing it by the total about of items (n)?